# How to set an image or colour on the map (html) coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use colors in the coordinates of map instead of the transparent clickable space.
When I click the circle (I am working only with circles) the colour should change (example from red to blue).

I have tried with background-color but this doesn't work, I think the correct way to do this is with javascript or jquery.

```
<img src="mapworld.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="mapworld" usemap="#mapworld">
<map name = "mapworld">
  <area id = "s1" target="_blank" alt="Circle1" title="Position 1" 
        href="www.google.com.ec" coords="10, 20, 4" shape="circle">
</map>
```

Comment: Could you include a screenshot including the circle that you want to change the color of?

Or just simply a screenshot of the HTML elements included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I have discovered this JQuery library which takes care of highlighting areas automatically and all you have to do is call the `.maphilight()` on your image when the `document` is `ready`.

You will need to download and implement these two files in your html file:

JQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

This one will have to be in a seperate file and included **after** `JQuery` (in your html file ofc).
**MapHighlight lib:** https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kemayo/maphilight/master/jquery.maphilight.js

Here's a JSFiddle to show a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8Lw7saf6/1/

**Usage:**

```
/* JQUERY */
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('img[usemap]').maphilight();

});
```

here are two demos from the [doc](https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/) :
 https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html
https://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_world.html